# Can we auto size content to center when viewing SSRS reports?

Tags: ssrs-2016

Display center when viewed in report services

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wish to show your first two column middle align or should be in middle of a column.
What you need to do is click on the cell in 1st column then press F4, you will have a property window on right bottom hand side.
There you can choose how to wish to see your column value.
Right, left or center.
Property is called “TextAlign”.
Link for reference:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3546/sql-server-reporting-services-text-box-orientation/

Answer (score 0):

thank you but that is not what I meant. Just to rephrase on what I posted. Let say a user has a 21 inch screen and the other user has 15 inch screen. When viewing the SSSRS report it should auto centre according to the screen size. I hope this helps..